# Is there a way to covert GridView.Rows back to List<Customer>

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and its datasource is `List<Customer>.` When I postback, is there an easy way to convert `Gridview1.Rows` back into my `List<Customer>`? I know I can loop through them manually, but was just wondering if there was an even easier way.

Comment: If the list is small and you don't have a gazillion users, you could keep the list of customers at the server in session state.  If you do have many users and the list of customers is the same for all of them, you could store it in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You said you fill the GridView using DataSource, so its possible to you fill the list back like this.

```
List<Customer> customers = DataGridView1.DataSource as List<Customer>;
```